# Mysql match between two values as list

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have two tables I want to match records like this

```
SELECT * FROM records1
WHERE records1.set IN (SELECT records2.p
FROM `records2`
WHERE rcords2.id=1200 )
```

I test it only with this query:

```
SELECT (records2.p)
FROM `records2`
WHERE rcords2.id=1200
```

Its giving results

```
p
========
14, 12, 80
```

And there is records1.set values like this

```
set
=============
80, 20, 60
```

And it didn't match it why?

Comment: Try this query: `SELECT r1.* FROM records1 r1 INNER JOIN records2 r2 ON r1.set = r2.p WHERE r2.id = 1200;`

Comment: not working because I can't using = to list values with comma

Comment: hold on, I'm confused. Do you mean that the entries are stored in your database with commas in the actual field (like each row returned for the column `p` has three comma-separated values), or in your example above, where you listed the results for `p`, do you mean that there are three rows returned...one with the value 14, one with 12, and one with 80?

Comment: Its store by comma
for exmp: 14, 15, 18 = 12, 14, 0 - TRUE / 14, 15, 18 = 12, 17, 0 - FALSE

Comment: This seems like very bad database design. You should avoid storing comma-separated values in your database, ESPECIALLY if you want to query based on only parts of that cell.

Comment: I know Its bad db desing I didn't desing it and I should work with it.

BTW. this is return true results SELECT * FROM records
WHERE records.set IN (14, 15, 18) but when I'm using a different table to match this instead of the values Isn't working.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the `SET` datatype (and it looks like nobody should be). I'm not sure why your `WHERE...IN` query worked, but it seems to me like you would need to (somehow) split `records2.p` and then use the `FIND_IN_SET` function using the individual values. This is going to get ridiculously complicated, since there isn't even a `SPLIT` function in MySQL in the first place...maybe you could do something like [this](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mysql-stored-procedure-split-delimited-string-into-rows). And then see if the result of that works with `FIND_IN_SET`.

Answer (score 0):

Your number of different set values is finit. So this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM records1, records2
WHERE (rcords2.id=1200) and (
    ((FIND_IN_SET('12', records1.set) > 0) and (FIND_IN_SET('12', records2.p) > 0)) or
    ((FIND_IN_SET('14', records1.set) > 0) and (FIND_IN_SET('14', records2.p) > 0)) or
    ((FIND_IN_SET('60', records1.set) > 0) and (FIND_IN_SET('60', records2.p) > 0)) or
    ((FIND_IN_SET('80', records1.set) > 0) and (FIND_IN_SET('80', records2.p) > 0)) or
    ...
)
```

And also binary operations are possible if the sets of both tables are defined in the same way (in the same order):

```
select * from records1, records2
where (rcords2.id=1200) and (records1.set & records1.set);
```

This works only if both colums are of the type set('12','14','60','80',...)

If its a comma seperated list in a string-field the sql-statement could look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM records1, records2
WHERE (records2.id=1200) and (
(CONCAT(",", records2.p, ",") like CONCAT("%,", substring_index(substring_index(records1.set, ',', 1), ',', -1), ",%")) or
(CONCAT(",", records2.p, ",") like CONCAT("%,", substring_index(substring_index(records1.set, ',', 2), ',', -1), ",%")) or
(CONCAT(",", records2.p, ",") like CONCAT("%,", substring_index(substring_index(records1.set, ',', 3), ',', -1), ",%")) or
(CONCAT(",", records2.p, ",") like CONCAT("%,", substring_index(substring_index(records1.set, ',', 4), ',', -1), ",%")) or
...
(CONCAT(",", records2.p, ",") like CONCAT("%,", substring_index(substring_index(records1.set, ',', N), ',', -1), ",%"))
)
```

If the string field is varchar(X) than there are less than X/2 possible values in the field, so replace N with X/2 in my SQL-Statement.

Comment: I can't use it because the values come from other table.

Comment: which values come from which table?

Comment: The values of the index search. Come from different table And I cannot know how many there is.

Comment: It's verfy difficult to understand you. "The values of the index search." is not a complete sentence. What do you mean with "index search"? Are you searching for an index? You said you have two tables: 'records1' and 'records2'. So which of theses tables is the 'other' table? Or are there even more tables?